# Nodejs: same code working at home but gives ECONNREFUSED at work

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im totaly new to javascript and node.js.
I was following the guide at http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-nodejs/page/4# and it was fully functioning at home.
But i want to make a gadget at work and the code want work there.
I always get a

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
```

someone maybe got a tipp what to search for for an solution?

I googled now several hours and cant find anything that i think is a solution or I cant atleast understand if its a solution :)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Im on Win7 64bit and got node version 0.10.25.
I tried out TCPview and the node.exe closes with State "SYN_SENT"...

Comment: Sorry to ask that, but how do I know? I didnt needed to setup up anything like that and when i tell windows firewall to accept all in and out connections, nothing changes.

Comment: Node.js is not hosted by all hosting services, Some of them provide hosting node.js some don't.

Comment: @JohnTaa, what are you even talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably behind a proxy

Does this work? Change the proxy with the your corporate proxy

```
var r = request.defaults({'proxy':'http://localproxy.com'})
```

It might be useful if your post your specific implementation in your question

Comment: You need to use `r` to do the requests, post your code

Answer (score -1):

I guess the network configuration are different at your home and at work.
You might have some missing permissions to connect to specific website, or listen on specific port.

Comment: This answer is really, really vague

Comment: Yes, i think that too, but the problem is, how do I find out, whats causing the problem?